# Calculating currency conversion before transaction using Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

Is it possible to calculate currency conversion before performing a transaction using Stripe?

I understand that the quoted conversion may not match the conversion rate used at the actual time of the transaction; but I would like to use a conversion rate before the transaction is performed and, if possible, avoid using a third party.

Comment: No, you can't get it in advance from the Stripe API, but it's available in the balance transaction associated with the charge after the charge is made : https://stripe.com/docs/api?#balance_transaction_object-exchange_rate